# Como impedir que um Input Required já comece com o estilo de CSS :invalid

Tags: html, css, html5, css3, input

Quando tenho um `input` `required` que tem algum estilo de CSS quando é `:invalid`, mesmo antes do usuário interagir com o `input` ele já fica estilizado como invalido. Como eu posso evitar isso?

Veja o exemplo:

```css
input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
input:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}
input {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
Esse input já começa estilizado com inválido, mesmo sem o usuário ter interagido com ele: <br>
<input type="email" required placeholder="email">
```

Porem eu gostaria que ele só ficasse estilizado como `:invalid` depois de preenchido e invalidado por patter, ou outro atributo de HTML, e não antes do usuário clicar nele nem nada.

**OBS1:** *Gostaria de uma opção apenas com CSS*

**OBS2:** *Se o campo for preenchido com valores inválido ele deve continuar estilizado como inválido, mesmo depois que o usuário tirar o foco do campo*

Comment: Eu acho meio complicado fazer isso com CSS puro. Eu ia sugerir o `:active`, mas isso funcionaria apenas em inputs que fosse focado.
`

Comment: Com o angular, eu geralmente uso a classe `ng-touched` ou `ng-dirty` pra identificar, mas ainda vou ver se é possível uma solução

Comment: @WallaceMaxters eu tentei usando :focus pra ver se consegui, mas tb não cheguei no resultado que queria... Com React ou Angular devem ter opções mesmo e até com jQuery imagino

Comment: @AlvaroAlves se for com a pseudo-class :focus ficaria grato, mas se for com o .focus do jQuery ainda prefiro esperar alguma resposta com CSS, mas fique a vontade para contribuir

Comment: `input:invalid:focus {
  border: 2px solid red;
}`
porém ai quando perde o focus ele perde o estilo

Comment: @AlvaroAlves pois é, eu já tinha tentado com :focus, mas não rolou :/

Comment: É, a princípio também não vejo uma saída com apenas CSS, mas ainda pesquisarei mais. Com JS poderia ser algo como: http://jsfiddle.net/dp2zuwnk/3/, onde define um atributo do elemento que ele já sofreu interação do usuário e pode receber o estilo `:invalid`.

Comment: veja se isso te ajuda: https://codepen.io/alvaro-alves/pen/zJzpMG?editors=1111

Comment: Ajuda? https://codepen.io/valdeir2000/pen/PdKeoz?editors=1100#0

Comment: @ValdeirPsr sim, 90% rss, mas quando eu tiro o foco ele perde o estilo :invalid, o campo só mostra que está invalido quando o cara clica nele

Comment: É, acho que só CSS não rola.

Answer (score 4):

**Primeiramente** essa não é uma resposta definitiva, ela não funciona nos browsers da Microsoft... *para variar...*

Agora vamos ao que interessa.

O que acontece aqui é que o `input` deve ter um valor de `placeholder`, e quando ele não tiver o `placeholder` é pq o usuário escreveu algo dentro do `input` correto. Mas como verificar se o `input` está ou não com o `placeholder`? É ai que entre essa regra do CSS `:not(:placeholder-shown)`.

Ou seja se tiver algum valor no `input` ele não tera o `placeholder`, e se esse valor for invalido ele estiliza o `input` com o `:invalid`. Dessa forma `input:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid`

Veja que agora o input tem 3 estados e 3 estilos diferentes. *Azul* quando `:focus`, *Vermelho* quando `:invalid` e *Verde* quando `:valid`

```css
input {
  width: 100px;
}
input:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0050e6;
}
input:required:valid {
  border: 2px solid #009900;
}
input:required:not(:placeholder-shown):invalid  {
  border: 2px solid #c9001b;
}
```

```html
<input type="email" placeholder="email" required name="" id="">
<input type="email" autofocus placeholder="email" required name="" id="">
<input type="email" value="123" placeholder="email" required name="" id="">
<input type="email" value="eu@eu.com" placeholder="email" required name="" id="">
<input type="email" placeholder="sem required sem validação" name="" id="">
```

**OBS1:** Consulte o suporte do seu browser sobre a pseudo-classe `:placeholder-shown`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown

**OBS:2** A documentação da Mozilla sobre `:placeholder-shown` pode ser vista aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown