# Colocar um IF no CSS

Tags: html, css

Eu tenho um CSS que mostra e oculta uma `div`. 
Porém eu quero que isso aconteça somente se este campo abaixo estiver preenchido, ou seja, se for diferente de vazio.

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="return BuscaDados(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor(this.value);" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor" />
```

Ele mostra essa `div`:

```
<div class="col-md-5 div_teste" id="mostrar">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor"></label>
    <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor"></label>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor"></label>
    <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Esse é o CSS:

```
#mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#passarmouse:hover #mostrar {
    display: block;
}

.div_teste {
    width: 350px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

Comment: Usa JavaScript para fazer a validação e alterar o estado do elemento.

Comment: Somente com CSS é impossível. **HTML ->** Estruturação; **CSS ->** `Estilização`; **JS ->** Comportamento.

Comment: Mariana dei uma solução só com CSS caso tenha alguma dúvida pode me dar um toque na resposta que tento te ajudar.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Vc pode fazer dessa forma apenas com CSS e a propriedade `:placeholder-shown`

A ideia é a seguinte, se o campo tiver um `placeholder` como valor vc pode fazer o `:hover` que nada acontece, mas se ele tiver algo digitado dentro logicamente o `placeholder` não estará mais presente, por isso usei `:not(:placeholder-shown)` para validar essa condição. Então quando o campo não tiver `placholder`, pois terá algo dentro, ai quando vc fizer o `:hover` a `div` aparece.

Parece meio confuso né, mas veja o código abaixo e faça o teste para ver funcionando.

```css
#mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#idfornecedor:not(:placeholder-shown):hover + #mostrar {
    display: block;
}

.div_teste {
    width: 350px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffffff;
    /* position: absolute; */
    z-index: 100;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="passarmouse">

    <input type="text" onkeypress="return BuscaDados(event);" onblur="CarregaFornecedor(this.value);" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor" placeholder="campo vazio" /> 

    <div class="col-md-5 div_teste" id="mostrar">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor">teste</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor"></label>
            <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor"></label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor"></label>
            <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor"></label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**OBS1:** Consulte o suporte do seu browser sobre a pseudo-classe :placeholder-shown: https://caniuse.com/#feat=css-placeholder-shown *(não funciona no IE ou Edge)*

**OBS:2** A documentação da Mozilla sobre :placeholder-shown pode ser vista aqui: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:placeholder-shown

Comment: No meu código ele funciona em partes, por exemplo, a parte de passar o mouse e aparecer, e tirar o mouse sumir, não funciona.

Comment: @marianac_costa ele só vai mostrar se tiver algum valor dentro do input e vc fizer o :hover, Vc quer que depois que coloque valor no input a div fique sempre visível?

Comment: Não, eu quero que a div seja preenchida, mas ela só apareça se passar o mouse nela, caso não esteja o mouse por cima, esconde a div..

Comment: Mas ela já está dessa forma aqui no exemplo... De uma olhada na estrutura do CSS e na estrutura do HTML, creio que haja algo diferente, por isso ai está funcionando parcialmente

Comment: Deu certinho, era isso mesmo que eu queria, desculpa, tinha um outro `css` atrapalhando, e deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: @marianac_costa legal que funcionou ai tb :), boa sorte com o projeto!

Answer (score 6):

Mariana, como comentado anteriormente com CSS "puro" é impossível realizar uma condição IF. Mas você pode usar JavaScript para alterar o comportamento do elemento sobre determinada situação.

Veja o exemplo com base no teu código:

```js
let inputFilter = document.querySelector("#idfornecedor");
let mostrar = document.querySelector("#mostrar");

inputFilter.addEventListener("input", function() {
  if (inputFilter.value != "") {
    mostrar.classList.add('show'); 
  } else {
    mostrar.classList.remove('show');
  }
});
```

```css
#mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#passarmouse:hover #mostrar {
    display: block;
}

.div_teste {
    width: 350px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
}

.show {
  display: block !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor"/>

<div class="col-md-5 div_teste" id="mostrar">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor"></label>
        <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor"></label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor"></label>
        <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor"></label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Foi capturado um evento de digitação em um `input` com o `addEventListener()` e executada uma função que verifica se o valor do `input` é diferente de vazio; se for, ele mostra a `div`, caso contrário esconde a mesma.

**Referências:**

- [MDN addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener)
- [MDN classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

Comment: Da pra fazer sim só com CSS, mas não é totalmente crossbrowser... :)

Comment: Me referi a essa condição dela, de pegar o estado do elemento (no caso diferente de vazio) e mostrar a `div`. Isso, só com CSS é impossível.

Comment: já vou postar a resposta, deixa eu pegar um café, mas vou querer meu +1 ok rss

Comment: @hugocsl: coloque uma resposta sobre isso. Deixe claro que pod não ser o melhor método - principalmente nesse caso, e aí ponha uma resposta legal - lembre-se, além de tirar dúvidas específicas, as respostas aqui se tornam um repositório de conhecimento e técnicas para outras pessoas com dúvidas semelhantes.

Comment: Dessa forma não deu certo, ele hora funciona, ou trava na tela, e ela não fica uma div flutuante. :(

Comment: Sobre a  `div` ser flutuante é questão de CSS nela. No meu exemplo só mostrei como você poderia fazer com JavaScript. Além disso, se executar o snippet vai reparar que funciona conforme a condição que você colocou na pergunta.

Comment: @jsbueno e João, missão dada é missão cumprida rss. Olha ai só com CSS, se tiverem alguma dúvida pode comentar lá. Eu usei essa técnica nessa resposta tb https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/327674/como-impedir-que-um-input-required-j%C3%A1-comece-com-o-estilo-de-css-invalid

Comment: @hugocsl baita resposta, show! :) +1 upvote

Comment: Foi o tempo do café :D

Answer (score 4):

Pode criar um [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input) [requerido](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required), que possui um [`pattern`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-pattern) que o formato válido seja [pelo menos um caracter](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1051998/4056678). E então, utilize [`:valid`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/:valid) para exibir o conteúdo quando a condição for satisfeita:

```css
.search-list {
  display: none
}

input:valid + .search-list {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<input type='text' placeholder='Buscar Fornecedor...' pattern='^\w*[\p{L}]\w*$' required>

<div class='search-list'>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Bem interessante a ideia!

Answer (score 0):

você pode resolver com javascript:

```js
var contador = 1;

function divGrande(){

 document.getElementById("minhaDiv").style.width = "400px";

}

function divPequena(){

 document.getElementById("minhaDiv").style.width = "200px";

}

function mudarTamanho(){


 if(contador == 1){
 document.getElementById("minhaDiv").style.width = "200px";
 contador = 0;
 }else{
 contador = 1;
  document.getElementById("minhaDiv").style.width = "400px"; 
  
 }



}
```

```css
#minhaDiv{
width:400px;
height:400px;
background-color:#000;
color:#FFF;

}
```

```html
<div id="minhaDiv">

Olá eu sou uma div

</div>
<br>
assim chamando a função através de clicks no botão
<br>

<button onclick="divGrande();">Div Grande</button>

<button onclick="divPequena();">Div Pequena</button>
<br>
E assim por If e Else
<br>
<button onclick="mudarTamanho();">Mudar Tamanho</button>
```

Comment: Cara  e o que é que isto tem a ver com a pergunta???!!