# Como fazer uso de seletores em CSS de modo que hajam duas condições simultâneas

Tags: html5, css3, css-seletores

Veja só:

1. A pergunta anotada como Duplicata, foi de minha autoria, recente!
2. Ainda não foi respondida, pois apesar de indicação de outro link, lá está 
   difusa a aplicação dos possíveis seletores, ou seja, não entendi.
3. É importante frisar que, nalgumas situações, tão somente a questão se resolve se alguém, de fato, resolver acrescentando ou alterando o snippet enviado, deixando o código funcionando como proposto, apenas isso!

É o que solicito, alteração do código para fazer funcionar na maneira proposta, ou seja, que os elementos `label` só retornem ao tamanho normal, se os campos, marcados como `required`, principalmente o *Email*, estiverem vazios e/ou inválidos.

No caso o `label` **Senha** retorna ao normal se o input estiver vazio, já o `label` **Usuário**, retorna se o input estiver vazio ou preenchido mas inválido.

Segue texto original da pergunta:

Bem, estou usando um bloco CSS no qual preciso alterar um elemento, mas essa alteração depende de que outros dois elementos correspondam a um determinado estado; exemplo:

para alterar `.textoAlteraçao`, é preciso que o elemento `.texto1` esteja com focus, e o elemento `.texto2` esteja vazio (ou válido/inválido).

---

**PS:** se eu uso separadamente, tipo:

```
#box form .texto1:focus ~ .textoAlteraçao {....}
```

ok, funciona, bem como se eu fizer:

```
#box form .texto2:empty ~ .textoAlteraçao;
```

ou ainda:

```
#box form .texto1:valid ~ .textoAlteraçao
```

Mas como juntar essas duas precedências (~)?

Ou seja, quero usar `~ .textoAlteracao` somente quando for precedido de duas condições de seletores. Acredito que exista um meio em CSS mesmo, e que deve até ser simples, mas tentei bastantes combinações e nada. Agradeço a ajuda.

Segue códigos: primeiro o estilo.css, depois o teste.html

```css
* {
 margin:0; padding:0;
}
body
{
 background-position:center; background-image: url("../IMAGENS/papel-de-parede-5.jpg");

}
#corpo-form div
{
 position:relative;
 display:block;
 height:55px;
 width:auto;
 margin:10px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-size:16pt;
 outline:none;
 background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
}
#corpo-form form .text
{
 height:90%;
 position:absolute;
 padding-left:5%;
 top:5%; 
 width:100%;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-size:12pt; 
 background:transparent;
 border:none;
 outline:none;
}
#corpo-form form .text:empty ~ .placehold
{
 height:90%;
 pointer-events:none;
 font-size:25pt;
 position:absolute;
 left:5%;
 top:20%; 
 color:rgba(0,0,0,.7);
 transition:.5s;
}

#corpo-form form .text:focus  ~ .placehold

{
 color:#ff265c;
 top:3%;
 left:2%;
 font-size:10pt;
 transition: .5s;
 font-weight:bolder;
}
input[type=submit]
{
 background-color:#20202f;
 color:#fff;
 cursor:pointer;
 border:none;
 width:100%;
 height:55px;
 border-radius:5px;
 font-size:16pt;
 outline:none;
 
}
input[type=submit]:hover
{
 background-color:rgba(179,134,0,0.8); color:#000;
}


#corpo-form h1, #corpo-form-cad h1
{
 text-align:center; color:#ffffff; padding:10px; font-size:30pt;
}
#corpo-form a
{
 margin:10px; text-align:center; text-decoration:none; color:#ffffff; display:block; padding-bottom:20px;
}
#corpo-form a:hover
{
 text-decoration:underline; font-size:14pt;
}

#corpo-form
{
 width:420; margin:130px auto 0px auto; background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

#corpo-form-cad
{
 width:420; margin: 100px auto 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
 <title>Projeto Login</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="CSS/estilo.css">
 <script type="text/javascript" src="JS/funcoes.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id ="corpo-form">
 <form  method="POST">
  <h1>Login</h1>

  <div>
   <input type="email"   class="text text2" name="email" id="email" required>
   <label class="placehold"  name="email_hold">Usuário</label>
  </div>
  <div>
   <input type="password"   class="text" name="senha" id="senha" required>
   <label class="placehold"  name="senha_hold">Senha</label>
  </div>
  <div class="class_submit">
   <input type="submit"  value="Acessar" onclick="valida_acesso()">
  </div>
  <br>
  <a href="cadastrar.php">Ainda nao é inscrito?<strong> Cadastre-se!</strong></a>
 </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

De modo que os elementos "Label" só retornem ao tamanho normal se o respectivo input estiver vazio ou inválido, senao, eles permanecem minificados, acima do texto do input! Penso que para isso, teria que javer um jeito de dizer ao renderizador: só mude tal elemento, se ele for precedido "disso" E "disso" (condições).

Comment: Talvez essa outra pergunta te ajude a fazer o "and" no seu seletor: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2797091/4730201

Comment: Ricardo, o link que vc passou, realmente é interessante, mas... desenvolveram muuuita teoria, e na prática, não vi solução da questão apresentada pelo usuário. Outra coisa, se vc ou alguém entendeu como funcionam seletores para a questão, façam-me grande gentileza de alterar o meu código que postei, solucionando o ponto que propus.. simples assim! Alguém que sacou bem, manda um snippet complementar/corretivo do que postei aqui, funcionando, e pronto. Obrigado pela atenção!

Comment: Ok! resolvido... ufa! Coloquei uma propriedade placeholder no Html e, no CSS, coloquei o filtro: `code`#corpo-form form input[type="email"]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placehold . Conforme sugerido por **hugocsl**, em [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328723/colocar-um-if-no-css/328743#328743)

Comment: Corrigindo meu comentário:  Ok! resolvido... ufa! Coloquei uma propriedade placeholder no Html e, no CSS, coloquei o filtro: `#corpo-form form input[type="email"]:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ .placehold`. Conforme sugerido por **hugocsl**, em [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/328723/colocar-um-if-no-css/328743#328743). E no placeholder, apenas deixei com um espaço em branco, para nao aparecer e nao atrapalhar. Grato a todos!