# Verificação de valor CSS

Tags: html, css

Algum tempo atrás eu até fiz esta pergunta aqui no fórum, onde responderam [link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/328732/72989) e me ajudaram muito.

Ficou desta forma:

```css
#mostrar {
    display: none;
}

#idfornecedor:not(:placeholder-shown):hover + #mostrar {
    display: block;
}

.div_teste {
    width: 350px;
    height: 120px;
    background: #ffffff;
    /* position: absolute; */
    z-index: 100;
    top: 30%;
    left: 40%;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<div id="passarmouse">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="FornecedorID" id="idfornecedor" placeholder="campo vazio" /> 

    <div class="col-md-5 div_teste" id="mostrar">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="fornecedor">teste</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="nomefornecedor">teste</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="ruafornecedor">teste</label>
            <label class="control-label" id="nfornecedor">teste</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <label class="control-label" id="bairrofornecedor">teste</label>
            <label class="control-label" id="cidadefornecedor">teste</label>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Só que vai ter um texto que eu vou inserir em `idfornecedor` que quando for ele, eu não quero que a `div` seja mostrado igual quando não está preenchido. Tem alguma forma de fazer isso baseado no código que já tenho ?

Comment: Só com JavaScript. Mas, qual o texto que vc vai inserir? Não ficou muito claro.

Comment: Quando ele pesquisar e não achar o valor no banco ele retorna `"Não encontrado, pesquise novamente."`, é ai que eu gostaria que não mostrasse a `div` flutuante

Comment: Vou deixar pra outro amigo tentar resolver pq eu não consegui entender o que pretende fazer. :D

Comment: não seria melhor colocar um data-status="valid/invalid" no input dependendo se ele encontrar ou não o que foi pesquisado, ai vc mostra ou não a div usando esse valor como seletor pelo css

Comment: @hugocsl vou verificar, eu postei o meu código, pois queria saber se dava pra fazer algo em cima do que eu já tenho, sem muito impacto.